# Regular Expression - Include Paragraph After Last Group

Tags: regex, vba

I am trying to solve the following regular expression:

https://regex101.com/r/pB0mD5/1

I would like to add an optional group to capture the paragraph of text (if any) between each Match.

So the last group for the first match would be:

```
"[General:] RVSM exclusive airspace FL290 to FL410, using the single alternate flight level allocation system described in Annex 2, Appendix 3a, except track allocation shall be 270 to 089 degrees (north), in lieu of 000 to 179 degrees (east), and shall be 090 to 269 degrees (south), in lieu of 180 to 359 degrees (west). Transponder mandatory - all controlled airspace (CTR and CTA) within the NZ FIR."
```

And the last group for the second match would be:

```
[General:] RNP airspace FL245 to FL600. RVSM airspace FL290 to FL410 Transponder mandatory - all oceanic control areas (OCA) within the Auckland Oceanic FIR.
```

VBA Code to test expression:

```
Sub TestExp()
    Dim sTest As String
    Dim sExpression As String

    sTest = Range("A1").Value 
    sExpression = "(?s)(NZZ[A-Z\d\_\-]*)\s([A-Z\(\) ]*)\s(SECTOR|FIR-P|FIR)\s([0-9]*)*\s*(FT|FL)?(.*?)(?=\n\bNZZ|\z)"
    Call ReadExpression(sResult, sExpression)
End Sub
Sub ReadExpression(strData As String, sExpression As String)
    Dim myRegExp As RegExp
    Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim myMatch As Match

    Set myRegExp = New RegExp
    myRegExp.Global = True
    myRegExp.MultiLine = True
    myRegExp.Pattern = sExpression

    Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(strData)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ii As Integer
    Dim strMatch As String

    i = shtOutput.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    For Each myMatch In myMatches
        i = i + 1
        For ii = 1 To myMatch.SubMatches.Count
          shtOutput.Cells(i, ii).Value = myMatch.SubMatches(ii - 1)
        Next
        DoEvents
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: **[`check`](https://regex101.com/r/pB0mD5/2)**

Comment: If you are using a language, you could also write a parser which examines each line.  This might be easier to maintain than a complex regex.

Comment: @rock321987 Can you post as answer please that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex can be used

```
(?s)(NZZ[A-Z\d\_\-]*)\s([A-Z\(\) ]*)\s(SECTOR|FIR-P|FIR)\s([0-9]*)*\s*(FT|FL)?(.*?)(?=\n\bNZZ|\z)
        <--------->     <-------->
     can be written as   No need
           [\w-]*      to escape ()
                    in character class
```

**[RegexDemo](https://regex101.com/r/pB0mD5/4)**

**NOTE**

```
(?s) # It allows matching . with new lines (Alternative :- [\S\s])
(?= #Lookahead
 \nNZZ #Match NZZ only if its followed by new line, otherwise it can match NZZ if its in middle of text
 |
 \z #End of string
)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I might have jumped the gun,  I am also trying to use this in excel vba.  MS VbScript Regular Expressions 5.5.  The execution fails with no specific error messages.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Reafidy can you share the code on ideone or any other site

Comment: I have updated the original question to include the vba code I am using to test the expression.  Is that what you needed?

Comment: @Reafidy you can try `(?s)(NZZ[A-Z\d\_\-]*)\s+([A-Z\(\) ]*)\s+(SECTOR|FIR-P|FIR)\s+([0-9]*)*\s*(FT|FL)?(.*?)(?=\nNZZ|\z)` regex.. meanwhile I think it has something to do with capturing groups..

Comment: It doesn't like the (?s) at the start of the expression.

Comment: @Reafidy i am not sure about the problem..will update you if I find any solution

Comment: Thanks is there a way to do it without the (?s) at the start because that seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Reafidy you can try this `(NZZ[A-Z\d\_\-]*)\s([A-Z\(\) ]*)\s(SECTOR|FIR-P|FIR)\s([0-9]*)*\s*(FT|FL)?([\S\s]*?)(?=\nNZZ|\z)`

Comment: @Reafidy instead of `(?s)`, you can use `new Regex(Regex, RegexOptions.Singleline)`

Comment: Oh I understand now, that's an inline modifier for single line.